# C++ Undefined Reference to Dime Library, Can't compile in QT

Tags: c++, qt, reference, compilation, qmake

Probably similar questions are asked many times. However I couldn't solve my problem with any current answer. I hope to get a quick answer.

In **QT C++**, I'm trying to use **Dime library** which is from:
https://bitbucket.org/Coin3D/dime/overview

I have a compiled **.lib** file of Dime library for windows. It's working with my friend's machine under Visual Studio.
So I have all headers and **dime.lib** file.

In my .pro file, I do:

```
QT       += core gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = dimeTest
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp
HEADERS  += mainwindow.h
FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

LIBS += -L$$PWD/src/release/ -ldime
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/src
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/src
PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/src/release/dime.lib
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/include
```

**$$PWD/include** folder has all .h header files.
**$$PWD/src/release** includes that lib file.

in my main.cpp, I just try to define a variable as DimeLine, but can't get it work.
this is from a new qt project.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

#define DIME_NOT_DLL
#include <dime/entities/Line.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    dimeLine line; //please help!! :)

    return a.exec();
}
```

Error output:

```
undefined reference to `dimeLine::dimeLine()'
undefined reference to `vtable for dimeExtrusionEntity'
undefined reference to `dimeEntity::~dimeEntity()'
undefined reference to `vtable for dimeExtrusionEntity'
undefined reference to `dimeEntity::~dimeEntity()'
:-1: error: release/main.o: bad reloc address 0x13 in section `.eh_frame'
collect2.exe:-1: error: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Please help me to compile that, How can i use Dime Library in a QT project? I tried many ways to write a correct **.pro file**. Non of them worked. Always had same error messages as undefined reference to 'what i use'.  I always do clean & qmake.

The current .pro file above is created with automatic way to click 'Add Library' option on the project.

I hope, an experienced guy can easily compile this.

All best!

UPDATE*1
I'm trying to re-compile Dime on my machine, may be problem is about trying to use that vs lib for qt, if anyone can help me also with compiling Dime : https://bitbucket.org/Coin3D/dime/overview on windows machine for QT Creator(uses mingw g++) I'll be sooo glad!!

Comment: What is this for `#define DIME_NOT_DLL`?

Comment: include\dime\Basic.h:172: error: #error Define either DIME_DLL or DIME_NOT_DLL as appropriate for your linkage! See dime/Basic.h for further instructions.
 #    error Define either DIME_DLL or DIME_NOT_DLL as appropriate for your linkage! See dime/Basic.h for further instructions.
      ^

Comment: if I don't put that line, it says the message above. My lib is not dynamic, not a dll, so static. so I put DIME NOT DLL, seems appropriate one. If I say DIME DLL, then it's giving another error set as(and many) :-1: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN8dimeLineC1Ev'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by compiling the **DIME library** on my windows machine with msys. Here I'd like to share what steps I had, which mistakes: I hope it helps someone else.

-Firstly I had a **.lib** file from a friend, he was using **Visual Studio** however I observed that is not wokring with minwg g++ at all.

-So if you compile the library with **Visual C++**, then you get a **.lib** file.
However when I compiled it with **g++** with **mingw** on **msys** console, I got an **.a** file which is worked well with **QT creator**

-Also under ubuntu there is an already compiled version of that library libdime, the file is libdime.so, however don't try to get it run on windows :))

For Compiling Dime Library,

1-) Download all Source project from **https://bitbucket.org/Coin3D/dime**

2-) Install Mingw + msys, and be sure u added "**C:\MinGW\bin**" to your Path, because msys will need it, anyway then with **msys console**. CD to your dime folder.

3-) firstly need to **configure** it,

```
./configure --prefix=c:/yourDestinationForCompiledDIME
```

4-) you can check whether make can work correctly. Do **not have any space** on the dime folder where you are running those make, configure etc commands, otherwise it may fail.

```
make check
```

5-) make it

```
make
```

6-) now installing it,.

```
make install
```

Those are the steps for compiling Dime, now to add it to QT project

Now, Copy /**lib**/ and /**include**/ folders from c:/yourDestinationForCompiledDIME to your project folder. Lib folder should have .a libraries, and  include has the header files. Those all you need to add a library to QT.

in .pro file:

```
win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/ -ldime

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/lib
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/lib

win32-g++: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/lib/libdime.a

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/include
```

in your cpp code, Important points are.

```
#define DIME_NOT_DLL
```

and your header of course, whatever you need..

```
#include <dime/entities/Line.h>
```

All cpp code something like:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

#define DIME_NOT_DLL
#include <dime/entities/Line.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    dimeLine line; //please help!! :)

    return a.exec();
}
```

I hope it will be helpful to someone who need to sue Dime in QT project.

All best,..

Answer (score 0):

Well, after looking into the Dime sources, I noticed, that it requires using one of these two defines: `DIME_DLL` and `DIME_NOT_DLL`. I assume, that you are going to link to dime library statically, so, according to notes, you have to use `DIME_NOT_DLL` define. You can do that by adding the following line into your .pro file:

```
DEFINES += DIME_NOT_DLL
```

Comment: thanks for your time. I tried that, but it seemingly does same with #define DIME_NOT_DLL  Because when I added your line to .pro file, it said warning: "DIME_NOT_DLL" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define DIME_NOT_DLL
 ^.... So anyway, nothing changed on my undefined error messages.

Comment: @questioner,  `#define DIME_NOT_DLL` is not needed anymore.

Comment: yes sir! it's not needed! However they do the same thing. So defining DIME_NOT_DLL in .pro file and #define DIME_NOT_DLL did same. My error is still same. So basically, your suggestion to DEFINES += DIME_NOT_DLL is what I already did with #define DIME_NOT_DLL, isn't it??

Comment: @questioner, right, both have the same effect. BTW, do you build both Dime and your application with mingw?

Comment: No, as i mentioned in post, I got the dime.lib from a friend who is using visual studio. Now I'm just compiling Dime on my machine, let's see. I hope this is the problem, thanks a lot for your time. Do u think any other point to focus?

Comment: @questioner, I believe you have to compile both modules with the same compiler, otherwise it will not work. The error you got is expected.